# Data Decoder in Visual C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, string, hex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Sniffer_Data_Logger.Properties;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Timers;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

namespace Sniffer_Data_Logger
{
    public enum LogMsgType { Normal,Incoming,Error};

    public partial class FrmTerminal : Form
    {
        // Declare buffer & newline character for each string (09.05)
        const Boolean test = true;
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 20480;
        const string COLON = ":";
        const byte FRAME_BYTE = 0x3A;

        private SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 5250000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);    // Declare new COM Port & its parameters


        public FrmTerminal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                                                                     // Initialise componenets to load the form
            ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            // Datareceive event handler with string
            if (test)
            {
                this.Load += new EventHandler(FrmTerminal_Load);
            }
            else
            {
                ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);             // When data received through port call event handler
            }
        }
        private void FrmTerminal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Test();
        }
        //Test for the string display
        public void Test()
        {
            lbus2sniffer data = new lbus2sniffer();
            string[] inputs =
            {
                ": AA 01 00 13 6F BA 8B 18 85 BA 8B 18 0B 01 00 81 00 0D 00 00 C5 BA B5 82 22",
                ": AA 01 00 13 CA BA 8B 18 E2 BA 8B 18 0C 02 00 81 00 0D 00 00 00 DE 7B D6 39 1F"
            };
            //test if buffer contains return
            receiveData = "";
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                receiveData += input;
                if (receiveData.Contains(COLON))
                {
                    if (receiveData.Substring(1) != COLON)
                    {
                        int index = receiveData.IndexOf(COLON);
                        if (index >= 0)
                        {
                            receiveData.Remove(0, index + 1);
                            string first = "";
                            if (receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0) >= 0)
                            {
                                first = receiveData.Substring(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                                receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                first = receiveData;
                            }
                            int bytesParsed = lbus2sniffer.Parse(first);
                            if (bytesParsed < 0)
                            {
                                receiveData = "";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, bytesParsed);
                                string printstring = lbus2sniffer.Print();
                                Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, string.Format("Sniffer Logged in {0} \n\r", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")) + printstring);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            receiveData = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void EnableControl()
        {
            if (ComPort.IsOpen) btnOpenPort.Text = "& Close Port";
            else btnOpenPort.Text = "&Open Port";
        }

        // This function is for formatting data over Rich Text Box window of the Application
        private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype,String msg)
        {
            rtfTerminal.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {     
            rtfTerminal.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            rtfTerminal.SelectionFont = new Font(rtfTerminal.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
            rtfTerminal.AppendText(msg);
            rtfTerminal.ScrollToCaret();

        }));


        }
        // This function is to convert byte in to hex string
        private string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] data)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(/*data.Length * 3*/);
            foreach (byte b in data)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2,'0').PadRight(3,' ').Replace("AA",": AA"));
            return sb.ToString().ToUpper();
        }

        private void btnOpenPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool error = false;

            if (ComPort.IsOpen) ComPort.Close();                                            // Close Comport if its already open
            try
            {
                ComPort.Open();                                                             // Opent the ComPort

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { error = true; }
        }


        private string receiveData = "";
        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);                                                            // Capture data after every 10 sec
            if (!ComPort.IsOpen) return;                                                    // If comport is closed do nothing
            int bytes = ComPort.BytesToRead;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];                                                // Create byte array buffer to hold incoming data
            ComPort.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);                                                 // Read all data  from the port & store it in buffer

            receiveData += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);                                 // UTF8 Encoding for incoming string

            //test if buffer contains return
            if (receiveData.Contains(COLON))
            {
                if (receiveData.Substring(1) != COLON)
                {
                    int index = receiveData.IndexOf(COLON);
                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        receiveData.Remove(0, index + 1);
                        string first = "";
                        if (receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0) >= 0)
                        {
                            first = receiveData.Substring(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                            receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            first = receiveData;
                        }
                        int bytesParsed = lbus2sniffer.Parse(first);
                        if (bytesParsed < 0)
                        {
                            receiveData = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, bytesParsed);
                            string printString = lbus2sniffer.Print();
                            Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, String.Format("Sniffer Logged in {0}\n\r", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + printString /*ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Replace("AA","\nAA") */));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        receiveData = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            //string[] data = { ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Replace("AA", "\nAA") };

            //foreach (var preamble in data)
            //{

            //    int position = preamble.IndexOf("\nAA");
            //    if (position < 0)
            //        continue;
            //    Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, string.Format("Time: {0};" + " Data: {1};", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), preamble.Substring(position))/* + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Replace("AA", "\nAA")*/);
            //}

            // Show the user incoming data in Hex format & after each 10 second update the data coming & post it on the newline

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtfTerminal.Clear();                                                            // If clear button pressed, clear the reach text box 
        }

        // Save file on the folder as the form of plain text 
        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)| *.txt";
            if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && saveFileDialog1.FileName.Length >0)
            {
                rtfTerminal.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            //Console.WriteLine(now);
        }
        //Define receiver protocol Structure as per Protocol description mentioned in Prot.C
        public class lbus2sniffer
        {
            public static List<lbus2sniffer> cdata = new List<lbus2sniffer>();          // Make a list view of protocol in display window
            public byte preamble { get; set; }
            public byte version { get; set; }
            public byte reserved { get; set; }
            public byte cmd { get; set; }
            public List<byte> ts1 = new List<byte>();
            public List<byte> ts2 = new List<byte>();
            public int len { get; set; }
            public List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
            public byte crc { get; set; }

            enum State
            {
                PREAMBLE,
                VERSION,
                RESERVED,
                CMD,
                TS1,
                TS2,
                LEN,
                DATA,
                CRC
            }

            public static int Parse(string input)
            {
                Boolean valid = false;
                Boolean firstNibble = true;
                int index = 0;                  // Indicates number of bytes parsed
                string nibbleStr = "";
                byte nibble = 0;
                int ts1Count = 0;
                int ts2Count = 0;
                int dataCount = 0;

                lbus2sniffer newData = new lbus2sniffer();

                State state = State.PREAMBLE;
                for (index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
                {
                    if ((input[index] == ' ') || (input[index] == ':'))
                    {
                        firstNibble = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (firstNibble)
                        {
                            nibbleStr += input.Substring(index, 1);
                            firstNibble = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nibbleStr += input.Substring(index, 1);
                            if (!byte.TryParse(nibbleStr, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out nibble))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            firstNibble = true;

                            switch (state)
                            {
                                case State.PREAMBLE:
                                    newData.preamble = nibble;
                                    state = State.VERSION;
                                    break;
                                case State.VERSION:
                                    newData.version = nibble;
                                    state = State.RESERVED;
                                    break;
                                case State.RESERVED:
                                    newData.reserved = nibble;
                                    state = State.CMD;
                                    break;
                                case State.CMD:
                                    newData.cmd = nibble;
                                    state = State.TS1;
                                    break;
                                case State.TS1:
                                    newData.ts1.Add(nibble);
                                    if (++ts1Count == 4)
                                    {
                                        state = State.TS2;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case State.TS2:
                                    newData.ts2.Add(nibble);
                                    if (++ts2Count == 4)
                                    {
                                        state = State.LEN;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case State.LEN:
                                    newData.len = nibble;
                                    state = State.DATA;
                                    break;
                                case State.DATA:
                                    newData.data.Add(nibble);
                                    if (++dataCount == newData.len)
                                    {
                                        state = State.CRC;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case State.CRC:
                                    newData.crc = nibble;
                                    cdata.Add(newData);
                                    valid = true;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

                if (valid)
                {
                    return index;                                       // number of bytes parsed
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            public static string Print()
            {
                lbus2sniffer data = cdata.LastOrDefault();
                string message = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}",
                    data.preamble.ToString("x2"),
                    data.version.ToString(),
                    data.reserved.ToString(),
                    data.cmd.ToString("x2"),
                    String.Join(" ", data.ts1.Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))),
                    string.Join(" ", data.ts2.Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))),
                    data.len.ToString(),
                    string.Join(" ", data.data.Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))),
                    data.crc.ToString("x2")
                    );
                return message;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Sniffer_Data_Logger.Properties;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Timers;

namespace Sniffer_Data_Logger
{
    public enum LogMsgType { Normal,Incoming,Error};

    // Define receiver protocol Structure as per Protocol description mentioned in Prot.C
    public class lbus2sniffer
    {
        public static List<lbus2sniffer> cdata = new List<lbus2sniffer>();          // Make a list view of protocol in display window
        public byte preamble { get; set; }
        public byte version { get; set; }
        public byte reserved { get; set; }
        public byte cmd { get; set; }
        public byte ts1 { get; set; }
        public byte ts2 { get; set; }
        public int len { get; set; }
        public byte[] data { get; set; }
        public byte crc { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class FrmTerminal : Form
    {
        private SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 5250000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);    // Declare new COM Port & its parameters


        public FrmTerminal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                                                                     // Initialise componenets to load the form
            ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);             // When data received through port call event handler

        }

        private void EnableControl()
        {
            if (ComPort.IsOpen) btnOpenPort.Text = "& Close Port";
            else btnOpenPort.Text = "&Open Port";
        }

        // This function is for formatting data over Rich Text Box window of the Application
        private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype,String msg)
        {
            rtfTerminal.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {     
            rtfTerminal.SelectedText = string.Empty;
            rtfTerminal.SelectionFont = new Font(rtfTerminal.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
            rtfTerminal.AppendText(msg);
            rtfTerminal.ScrollToCaret();

        }));


        }
        // This function is to convert byte in to hex string
        private string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] data)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(/*data.Length * 3*/ );
            foreach (byte b in data)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3,' '));
            return sb.ToString().ToUpper();
        }

        private void btnOpenPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool error = false;

            if (ComPort.IsOpen) ComPort.Close();                                            // Close Comport if its already open
            try
            {
                ComPort.Open();                                                             // Opent the ComPort

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { error = true; }
        }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(10000);                                                            // Capture data after every 10 sec
            if (!ComPort.IsOpen) return;                                                    // If comport is closed do nothing
            int bytes = ComPort.BytesToRead;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];                                                // Create byte array buffer to hold incoming data
            ComPort.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);                                                 // Read all data  from the port & store it in buffer

            //byte[] buffer = new byte[63];                                                     // Buffer to store 64 bytes
            //ComPort.Read(buffer, 0, 63);                                                      // Read 64 bytes & store in buffer

            Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, string.Format("Sniffer Logged in {0}\n\r", DateTime.Now) + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Replace("AA","\nAA"));                         // Show the user incoming data in Hex format & after each 10 second update the data coming & post it on the newline

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtfTerminal.Clear();                                                            // If clear button pressed, clear the reach text box 
        }

        // Save file on the folder as the form of plain text 
        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)| *.txt";
            if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && saveFileDialog1.FileName.Length >0)
            {
                rtfTerminal.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(now);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to build a data Decoder using C# . net Framework.

Now i am getting data over my Windows form which reflect complete protocol structure on each line.

My protocol structure is:

[Protocol Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0hTd.png)

Currently io am getting results as below:

AA 01 00 13 6F BA 8B 18 85 BA 8B 18 0B 01 00 81 00 0D 00 00 C5 BA B5 82 22

AA 01 00 13 CA BA 8B 18 E2 BA 8B 18 0C 02 00 81 00 0D 00 00 00 DE 7B D6 39 1F

[Protocol Structure expected on RichTextBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kGFQ.jpg)

I tried to use substring method but i am getting exception when i am running the script.

So how i can decode Hex data string over Windows c# application?

Can i use DataGridStructure (Without SQL Server)?

Comment: Did you use any library for this?

Comment: I have converted Byte Array to hex strings & dispalyed. No Special library. Just normal Windows application form

Comment: Sure, then just convert the bytes back to string, perhaps you would need to use Encoding class to do that.

Comment: U mean i Need to convert Bytes to string? If yes then i already did it. Now i want to deocde the data

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
//using Sniffer_Data_Logger.Properties;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Timers;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

namespace Sniffer_Data_Logger
{
    public enum LogMsgType { Normal, Incoming, Error };

    public partial class FrmTerminal : Form
    {

        // Declare buffer & newline character for each string (09.05)
        const Boolean test = true;
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 20480;
        const string COLON = ":";
        const byte FRAME_BYTE = 0x3A;

        private SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 5250000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);    // Declare new COM Port & its parameters


        public FrmTerminal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();                                                                     // Initialise componenets to load the form
            ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
            // Datareceive event handler with string
            if (test)
            {
                this.Load += new EventHandler(FrmTerminal_Load);
            }
            else
            {
                ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);             // When data received through port call event handler
            }
        }
        private void FrmTerminal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Test();
        }
        //Test for the string display
        public void Test()
        {
            lbus2sniffer data = new lbus2sniffer();
            string[] inputs =
            {
                ": AA 01 00 13 6F BA 8B 18 85 BA 8B 18 0B 01 00 81 00 0D 00 00 C5 BA B5 82 22",
                ": AA 01 00 13 CA BA 8B 18 E2 BA 8B 18 0C 02 00 81 00 0D 00 00 00 DE 7B D6 39 1F"
            };
            //test if buffer contains return
            receiveData = "";
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                receiveData += input;
                if (receiveData.Contains(COLON))
                {
                    if (receiveData.Substring(1) != COLON)
                    {
                        int index = receiveData.IndexOf(COLON);
                        if (index >= 0)
                        {
                            receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, index + 1);
                            string first = "";
                            if (receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0) >= 0)
                            {
                                first = receiveData.Substring(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                                receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                first = receiveData;
                            }
                            int bytesParsed = lbus2sniffer.Parse(first);
                            if (bytesParsed < 0)
                            {
                                receiveData = "";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, bytesParsed);
                                string printString = lbus2sniffer.Print();
                                Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, string.Format("Sniffer Logged in {0}\t{1}\n\r", DateTime.Now, printString));  // Show the user incoming data in Hex format & after each 10 second update the data coming & post it on the newline
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            receiveData = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void EnableControl()
        {
            if (ComPort.IsOpen) btnOpenPort.Text = "& Close Port";
            else btnOpenPort.Text = "&Open Port";
        }

        // This function is for formatting data over Rich Text Box window of the Application
        private void Log(LogMsgType msgtype, String msg)
        {
            rtfTerminal.Invoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                rtfTerminal.SelectedText = string.Empty;
                rtfTerminal.SelectionFont = new Font(rtfTerminal.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
                rtfTerminal.AppendText(msg);
                rtfTerminal.ScrollToCaret();

            }));


        }
        // This function is to convert byte in to hex string
        private string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] data)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(/*data.Length * 3*/);
            foreach (byte b in data)
                sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3, ' ').Replace("AA", ": AA"));
            return sb.ToString().ToUpper();
        }

        private void btnOpenPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool error = false;

            if (ComPort.IsOpen) ComPort.Close();                                            // Close Comport if its already open
            try
            {
                ComPort.Open();                                                             // Opent the ComPort

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { error = true; }
        }


        private string receiveData = "";
        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);                                                            // Capture data after every 10 sec
            if (!ComPort.IsOpen) return;                                                    // If comport is closed do nothing
            int bytes = ComPort.BytesToRead;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];                                                // Create byte array buffer to hold incoming data
            ComPort.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);                                                 // Read all data  from the port & store it in buffer

            receiveData += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);                                 // UTF8 Encoding for incoming string

            //test if buffer contains return
            if (receiveData.Contains(COLON))
            {
                if (receiveData.Substring(1) != COLON)
                {
                    int index = receiveData.IndexOf(COLON);
                    if (index >= 0)
                    {
                        receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, index + 1);
                        string first = "";
                        if (receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0) >= 0)
                        {
                            first = receiveData.Substring(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                            receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, receiveData.IndexOf(COLON, 0));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            first = receiveData;
                        }
                        int bytesParsed = lbus2sniffer.Parse(first);
                        if (bytesParsed < 0)
                        {
                            receiveData = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            receiveData = receiveData.Remove(0, bytesParsed);
                            string printString = lbus2sniffer.Print();
                            Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, string.Format("Sniffer Logged in {0}\t{1}\n\r", DateTime.Now, printString));  // Show the user incoming data in Hex format & after each 10 second update the data coming & post it on the newline
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        receiveData = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            //string[] data = { ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Replace("AA", "\nAA") };

            //foreach (var preamble in data)
            //{

            //    int position = preamble.IndexOf("\nAA");
            //    if (position < 0)
            //        continue;
            //    Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, string.Format("Time: {0};" + " Data: {1};", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), preamble.Substring(position))/* + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Replace("AA", "\nAA")*/);
            //}

            // Show the user incoming data in Hex format & after each 10 second update the data coming & post it on the newline

        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtfTerminal.Clear();                                                            // If clear button pressed, clear the reach text box 
        }

        // Save file on the folder as the form of plain text 
        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)| *.txt";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && saveFileDialog1.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                rtfTerminal.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            //Console.WriteLine(now);
        }
        //Define receiver protocol Structure as per Protocol description mentioned in Prot.C
        public class lbus2sniffer
        {
            public static List<lbus2sniffer> cdata = new List<lbus2sniffer>();          // Make a list view of protocol in display window
            public byte preamble { get; set; }
            public byte version { get; set; }
            public byte reserved { get; set; }
            public byte cmd { get; set; }
            public List<byte> ts1 = new List<byte>();
            public List<byte> ts2 = new List<byte>();
            public int len { get; set; }
            public List<byte> data = new List<byte>();
            public byte crc { get; set; }

            enum State
            {
                PREAMBLE,
                VERSION,
                RESERVED,
                CMD,
                TS1,
                TS2,
                LEN,
                DATA,
                CRC
            }

            public static int Parse(string input)
            {
                Boolean valid = false;
                Boolean firstNibble = true;
                int index = 0;                  // Indicates number of bytes parsed
                string nibbleStr = "";
                byte nibble = 0;
                int ts1Count = 0;
                int ts2Count = 0;
                int dataCount = 0;

                lbus2sniffer newData = new lbus2sniffer();

                State state = State.PREAMBLE;
                for (index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
                {
                    if ((input[index] == ' ') || (input[index] == ':'))
                    {
                        firstNibble = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (firstNibble)
                        {
                            nibbleStr = input.Substring(index, 1);
                            firstNibble = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nibbleStr += input.Substring(index, 1);
                            if (!byte.TryParse(nibbleStr, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out nibble))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            firstNibble = true;

                            switch (state)
                            {
                                case State.PREAMBLE:
                                    newData.preamble = nibble;
                                    state = State.VERSION;
                                    break;
                                case State.VERSION:
                                    newData.version = nibble;
                                    state = State.RESERVED;
                                    break;
                                case State.RESERVED:
                                    newData.reserved = nibble;
                                    state = State.CMD;
                                    break;
                                case State.CMD:
                                    newData.cmd = nibble;
                                    state = State.TS1;
                                    break;
                                case State.TS1:
                                    newData.ts1.Add(nibble);
                                    if (++ts1Count == 4)
                                    {
                                        state = State.TS2;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case State.TS2:
                                    newData.ts2.Add(nibble);
                                    if (++ts2Count == 4)
                                    {
                                        state = State.LEN;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case State.LEN:
                                    newData.len = nibble;
                                    state = State.DATA;
                                    break;
                                case State.DATA:
                                    newData.data.Add(nibble);
                                    if (++dataCount == newData.len)
                                    {
                                        state = State.CRC;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case State.CRC:
                                    newData.crc = nibble;
                                    cdata.Add(newData);
                                    valid = true;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

                if (valid)
                {
                    return index;                                       // number of bytes parsed
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            public static string Print()
            {
                lbus2sniffer data = cdata.LastOrDefault();
                string message = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}",
                    data.preamble.ToString("X2"),
                    data.version.ToString(),
                    data.reserved.ToString(),
                    data.cmd.ToString("X2"),
                    String.Join(" ", data.ts1.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))),
                    string.Join(" ", data.ts2.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))),
                    data.len.ToString(),
                    string.Join(" ", data.data.Select(x => x.ToString("X2"))),
                    data.crc.ToString("X2")
                    );
                return message;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, did we missed Display command here? like console.writeline()

Comment: I just parsed the data.  Wasn't sure how you want to display data.  I would put data into a DataTable and then bind you control to the datatable.

Comment: I did some coding with Windows form which i will attach in the question. I managed to write data over text box. But without Splitting it. just normal hex string. However i dont want to connect my app to SQL Server.

Comment: I used following line to get data over Windows form;                                  Log(LogMsgType.Incoming, string.Format("Sniffer Logged in {0}\n\r", DateTime.Now) + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer).Replace("AA","\nAA"));

Comment: I updated code based on your latest posting.  The code is NOT tested.  I didn't like how you were getting each row of data so I made code more robust.  I assumed each line of data ended with a '\n'.

Comment: I did some testing on the code.  Can't guarantee it is perfect.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for Reply. i also did some Troubleshooting. now i almost removed all Errors. Just i am getting warning on ComPort Opening which Shows "unreachable Code detected". On Result window i am not gettign anything.

Comment: I think its unable to open the Serial port. In Test Loop its going in infinite Loop & not reaching till next Statement of ComPort.Open() due to which its showing warning "Unreachable Code detected". Wt you say?

Comment: About ("\n") in my origanal data which i am getting from serial port, i dont have any newline character in it. Its just plain data stream which we r converting to Hex. So when we are checking in Input [index] == '\n', it may go in infinite Loop. but its my opinion. Also in main data stream which we r getting from Serial port, each stream not ending with '\n'. Thats why i was inserting \n before "AA" which was my start of protocol.

Comment: Are you generating the serial data in another application?  Any serial stream needs to have an identify to indicate where data starts/ends.  It may be visible character or invisible character. Searching for an AA is not very smart because it may be in other places in the stream.

Comment: i am generating data with embedded board (UART type). This board is sending data over PC via Serial Port. So in orignal protocol (Embedded board) i dont have any Special character like '\n'. I just have premable ('AA') which indicates start of the protocol.

Comment: I would add a character like a colon ':' at the start of the each row of data and the '\n' (optional) at the end.  It would make it easier to sync on each row of data.

Comment: Suppose for a Trial if i want to use "AA" (as of now), instead of Colon how i can fetch it in Code?  Byte type or string?

Comment: If you change the  COLON to AA the current code will remove the first A.

Comment: I have replaced "AA" by ": AA" in stringbuilder so that it will produce string starting from ": xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx". But still i am not getting result over window. It showed me warning "Code Unreachable over line of "COMPort.Open()".

Comment: I fixed code above.  The unreachable code is due to test = true.  You can ignore or remove the IF when you are ready to test with the serial port.